# $x_\beta \rightarrow x$ in a locally convex space if and only if $\rho_\alpha(x_\beta, x) \rightarrow 0$ for every seminorm $\rho_\alpha$

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a locally convex space with the family of seminorms $\{p_\alpha\}$. I am trying to get a feel for convergence of nets (or sequences) in these spaces aside from the general topological definition of convergence.

An answer to an older question ([Convergence on locally convex spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3129567/convergence-on-locally-convex-spaces)) mentions that convergence in locally convex spaces can be characterized by: $x_\beta \rightarrow x$ in a locally convex space if and only if $\rho_\alpha(x_\beta, x) \rightarrow 0$ for every seminorm $\rho_\alpha$.

Does anyone know a reference where this result may be found or how it can be proved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $x_\beta \to x$.  Let $\varepsilon>0$.  Since
$$U=\{y:\rho(y-x)<\varepsilon\}$$
is an open neighborhood of $x$, there is some $\beta_0$ such that for all $\beta\ge\beta_0,\;x_\beta\in U$.  This means for all $\beta\ge\beta_0,\;\rho(x_\beta-x) < \varepsilon$.  Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, it follows that $\rho(x_\beta-x)\to 0$.

Conversely, assume $\rho(x_\beta-x)\to 0$ for all seminorms $\rho$ defining the topology.  A basic open neighborhood of $x$ has the form
$$V=\{y:\rho_1(y-x)<\delta,\dots,\rho_n(y-x)<\delta\}$$
for some seminorms $\rho_1,\dots\rho_n$ and $\delta>0$.  (Note: the actual definition of the topology uses different $\delta_i$ for $\rho_i$, but you can take $\delta=\min_i \delta_i$.)

Since $\rho_k(x_\beta-x)\to 0$ for each $k$, there is a $\beta_k$ such that $\rho_k(x_\beta-x)<\delta$ for $\beta\ge\beta_k$.  By the property of nets, there is some $\gamma\ge\beta_k$ for all $k$.  Then for all $\beta\ge\gamma$, for all $k$, $\rho_k(x_\beta-x)<\delta$.  So for all $\beta\ge\gamma,\,x_\beta\in V$.  Since $V$ was arbitrary, $x_\beta\to x$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.